# Android generated LoginActivity error(Incorrect password)

Tags: android, android-intent, authentication, android-asynctask

I am using the Android generated login activity and it keeps giving me incorrect password error even though my password is correct. I have checked my code several times but i can't find any errors. It just doesn't start my Home activity and reports the error. Can someone please check my code and correct me if i am doing something wrong...

**editted: Added full code

***editted: Solved this problem by checking my next activity which sets a session to redirect to login page when no session is logged in(apparently i missed that earlier on). Thanks  for all the help though.

```
 private static final String[] DUMMY_CREDENTIALS = new String[] {
        "foo@example.com:hello", "bar@example.com:world" };

public static final String EXTRA_EMAIL = "com.example.android.authenticatordemo.extra.EMAIL";

private UserLoginTask mAuthTask = null;
private String mEmail;
private String mPassword;
private EditText mEmailView;
private EditText mPasswordView;
private View mLoginFormView;
private View mLoginStatusView;
private TextView mLoginStatusMessageView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

    mEmail = getIntent().getStringExtra(EXTRA_EMAIL);
    mEmailView = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.email);
    mEmailView.setText(mEmail);

    mPasswordView = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);
    mPasswordView
            .setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onEditorAction(TextView textView, int id,
                        KeyEvent keyEvent) {
                    if (id == R.id.login || id == EditorInfo.IME_NULL) {
                        attemptLogin();
                        return true;
                    }
                    return false;
                }
            });

    mLoginFormView = findViewById(R.id.login_form);
    mLoginStatusView = findViewById(R.id.login_status);
    mLoginStatusMessageView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.login_status_message);

    findViewById(R.id.sign_in_button).setOnClickListener(
            new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    attemptLogin();
                }
            });
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.login, menu);
    return true;
}


public void attemptLogin() {
    if (mAuthTask != null) {
        return;
    }

    // Reset errors.
    mEmailView.setError(null);
    mPasswordView.setError(null);

    // Store values at the time of the login attempt.
    mEmail = mEmailView.getText().toString();
    mPassword = mPasswordView.getText().toString();

    boolean cancel = false;
    View focusView = null;

    // Check for a valid password.
    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(mPassword)) {
        mPasswordView.setError(getString(R.string.error_field_required));
        focusView = mPasswordView;
        cancel = true;
    } else if (mPassword.length() < 4) {
        mPasswordView.setError(getString(R.string.error_invalid_password));
        focusView = mPasswordView;
        cancel = true;
    }

    // Check for a valid email address.
    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(mEmail)) {
        mEmailView.setError(getString(R.string.error_field_required));
        focusView = mEmailView;
        cancel = true;
    } else if (!mEmail.contains("@")) {
        mEmailView.setError(getString(R.string.error_invalid_email));
        focusView = mEmailView;
        cancel = true;
    }

    if (cancel) {
        // There was an error; don't attempt login and focus the first
        // form field with an error.
        focusView.requestFocus();
    } else {

        mLoginStatusMessageView.setText(R.string.login_progress_signing_in);
        showProgress(true);
        mAuthTask = new UserLoginTask();
        mAuthTask.execute((Void) null);
    }
}


@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB_MR2)
private void showProgress(final boolean show) {

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB_MR2) {
        int shortAnimTime = getResources().getInteger(
                android.R.integer.config_shortAnimTime);

        mLoginStatusView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        mLoginStatusView.animate().setDuration(shortAnimTime)
                .alpha(show ? 1 : 0)
                .setListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
                    @Override
                    public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
                        mLoginStatusView.setVisibility(show ? View.VISIBLE
                                : View.GONE);
                    }
                });

        mLoginFormView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        mLoginFormView.animate().setDuration(shortAnimTime)
                .alpha(show ? 0 : 1)
                .setListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
                    @Override
                    public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
                        mLoginFormView.setVisibility(show ? View.GONE
                                : View.VISIBLE);
                    }
                });
    } else {
        // The ViewPropertyAnimator APIs are not available, so simply show
        // and hide the relevant UI components.
        mLoginStatusView.setVisibility(show ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE);
        mLoginFormView.setVisibility(show ? View.GONE : View.VISIBLE);
    }
}


public class UserLoginTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean> {
    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... params) {
        for (String credential : DUMMY_CREDENTIALS) {
            String[] pieces = credential.split(":");
            if (pieces[0].equals(mEmail)) {
                 // Account exists, return true if the password matches.
                 return pieces[1].equals(mPassword);

            }
        }
            // TODO: register the new account here.
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(final Boolean success) {
        mAuthTask = null;
        showProgress(false);
        if (success) {
            finish();
            Intent myIntent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, GarajHome.class);
            LoginActivity.this.startActivity(myIntent);
        } else {
            mPasswordView.setError(getString(R.string.error_incorrect_password));
            mPasswordView.requestFocus();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCancelled() {
        mAuthTask = null;
        showProgress(false);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@Override
        protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... params) {
           boolean isCorrect = false;
            for (String credential : DUMMY_CREDENTIALS) {
                String[] pieces = credential.split(":");
                if (pieces[0].equalsIgnoreCase(mEmail)&& pieces[1].equalsIgnoreCase(mPassword)) {

                          isCorrect=true;
                          break;

                }
            }
                // TODO: register the new account here.
            return isCorrect;
        }
```

HI i used your code and write mine removed some logic it working for me i think the code i removed problem is there look at my code

```
import android.animation.Animator;
import android.animation.AnimatorListenerAdapter;
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.annotation.TargetApi;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.pk.to_do_timer.R;



public class test extends Activity{
private static final String[] DUMMY_CREDENTIALS = new String[] {
        "foo@example.com:hello", "bar@example.com:world" };

public static final String EXTRA_EMAIL = "com.example.android.authenticatordemo.extra.EMAIL";

private UserLoginTask mAuthTask = null;
;

private EditText mEmailView;
private EditText mPasswordView;
private View mLoginFormView;
private View mLoginStatusView;
private TextView mLoginStatusMessageView;
private String mEmail="foo@example.com";
private String mPassword = "hello";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);



    findViewById(R.id.sign_in_button).setOnClickListener(
            new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    attemptLogin();
                }
            });
}




public void attemptLogin() {
    if (mAuthTask != null) {
        return;
    }



       // showProgress(true);
        mAuthTask = new UserLoginTask();
        mAuthTask.execute((Void) null);
    }





@SuppressLint("NewApi")
public class UserLoginTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean> {
    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... params) {
         boolean isCorrect = false;
         for (String credential : DUMMY_CREDENTIALS) {
             String[] pieces = credential.split(":");
             if (pieces[0].equalsIgnoreCase(mEmail)&& pieces[1].equalsIgnoreCase(mPassword)) {

                       isCorrect=true;
                       break;

             }
         }

             // TODO: register the new account here.
         return isCorrect;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(final Boolean success) {
        mAuthTask = null;

        if (success) {
            finish();
            Intent myIntent = new Intent(test.this, GarajHome.class);
            test.this.startActivity(myIntent);
        } 
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCancelled() {
        mAuthTask = null;
        //showProgress(false);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: I am still having the same error (incorrect password)

Comment: can you let me know the values of pieces and try   pieces[0].equalsIgnoreCase(mEmail) method just incase cases are different.

Comment: I'm sorry, it's still giving me the same error and i am very sure my dummy credentials are correct.

Comment: can you shre value of DUMMY_CREDENTIALS.

Comment: here are my DUMMY_CREDENTIALS `private static final String[] DUMMY_CREDENTIALS = new String[] {
   "foo@example.com:hello", "bar@example.com:world" }; `

Comment: dont write anything in the doInBackground method just return true then tell if its working.then we will see the problem.

Comment: I did that but nothing happens, it only refreshes the page. This is my logical when i sign in   `11-09 18:59:39.104: I/ActivityManager(21210): Timeline: Activity_launch_request id:com.lityum.garaj time:261510226
11-09 18:59:39.224: I/ActivityManager(21210): Timeline: Activity_launch_request id:com.lityum.garaj time:261510342
11-09 18:59:39.454: I/ActivityManager(21210): Timeline: Activity_idle id: android.os.BinderProxy@42928e30 time:261510578
`

Comment: meaning you are able to sign in now it is not giving you password incorrect error i think you should share more code of understanding.

Comment: I ran ur code but it is still giving me the same problem...could the problem be from my ADT or emulator??

Comment: you used my code as it is line by line  since it is working here.

Comment: I used exactly your code but it just comes back to the login page.

Comment: meaning it goes to GarajHome activity.then comes back.sice in my case i am able to  proceed to GarajHome activity.

Comment: Ok, so what do i have to do to make it stay in Garaj Activity?

Comment: it depends what have you written there(Garaj Activity).Are you able to move to Garaj Activity.

Comment: it doesn't move to any activity...i tried to change it to other activities but it still just comes back to the sign up page.

Comment: I figured out what was wrong, i had a session manager setup which redirects to Login page when no session is logged in and i had set up my session in GarajHome...thank you for your help though, it led the way to figure out my problem :)

Comment: can you upvote the answer it will be helpful for me . by clicking uparrow beside my answer. Thanks